# Error : Testapp is not responding

Tags: javascript, android, xml, eclipse

I am trying to make a simple calculator that can add, subtract, multiply and divide. It has 6 buttons , the two extra for showing the result "=" and the other one for clearing the edit text "C".  There are no errors but after running it on AVD on my Android Studios , error is showing->
your app is not responding.....Something is wrong and I don't know what. Can anyone tell the hidden error?
Below is the Java Class of my code and the Android Manifest for reference.

```
package com.example.lenovo.testapp;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.InputType;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
public class HomeScreen extends ActionBarActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
      int input1,input2;
       int sum=0;
      Button add,sub,mul,div,clear,equal;
      EditText display;
      String num1,num2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_screen);
    mul = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bMul);
    div = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bDiv);
    add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bAdd);
    sub = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSub);
    clear = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bClear);
    equal = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bEqual);
    display = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tvDisplay);
    clear.setOnClickListener(this);
    equal.setOnClickListener(this);
    div.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            display.setText(null);
            display.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
            num2 = display.getText().toString();
            input2 = Integer.parseInt(num2);
            sum=input1/input2;
        }
    });
    add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            display.setText(null);
            display.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
            num2 = display.getText().toString();
            input2 = Integer.parseInt(num2);
            sum=input1+input2;

        }
    });
    sub.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            display.setText(null);
            display.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
            num2 = display.getText().toString();
            input2 = Integer.parseInt(num2);
            sum=input1-input2;
        }
    });
    mul.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            display.setText(null);
            display.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
            num2 = display.getText().toString();
            input2 = Integer.parseInt(num2);
            sum=input1*input2;
        }
    });

    display.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
    num1 = display.getText().toString();
    input1 = Integer.parseInt(num1);


}
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    if(clear.isPressed())
    {
        display.setText(null);
    }
    if(equal.isPressed())
    {
        display.setText(sum);
    }

}
}
```

Manifest.xml:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/joey_tribbiani"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".HomeScreen"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.lenovo.testapp.HOMESCREEN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: Remove <action android:name="com.example.lenovo.testapp.HOMESCREEN" />

Comment: @ПетърПетров ....done , but still the same error :(.....what I am doing wrong?

Comment: i dont see the error , i guess is from tags , must be 
<intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>

Comment: Ok thanks....but is there no error in the java class?

Comment: no , your logic is wrong , you set text to null first and then try to get text , but its already null

Comment: Basically , it requires 2 values to perform any operation so after getting first number from the user I erased the edit text ,saved it in an integer variable and then again taken 2nd number in another integer variable.

Comment: i dont see where you place input1. you try to get firt value outside listener so it will execute on creating. that means your input1 will always "" or null

Comment: Input2 will get its value after user touches any of the operators , but initially the user will not touch any button so input1 will get its value before input2 and then after the user touches any of the operators input2 will be assigned its value..........does this makes sense?